# Ubuntu 16.4 installation unknown error

Tags: installation, ubuntu-16.04

I am facing this problem, please see this image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should try by changing the language to English from Bengali.

Comment: I did, but still the same problem. I tried different versions ( 16.04 & 16.10 ). But it's still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following instructions went well for me:

### How to install Ubunto 16.4 TLS on a fresh PC (amd64)?

1. Insert a USB key, larger than 2GB
2. Format the USB with FAT32: Spotlight --> Disk Utility --> ms-FAT + GUID
3. Mount the ISO file to the USB key with unetbootin app
4. Boot the target PC from the USB key, in UEFI mode
5. Lunch "Install Ubunto" with adding the following boot-keys (next to quiet splash):  pci=noaer pci pcie_aspm=off
6. Complete the installation --> choose "Erase disk and install" (fresh) and choose to update everything during installation
7. When installation complete, reboot and then add the additional boot-keys (step 5 above) to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in /etc/default/grub
8. sudo update-grub

Good luck,
Shahar